Lagrange’s four-square theorem: making the proof “trivial” by increasing four to a larger constant?
I teach an introductory discrete mathematics course. Unlike many such courses, we do not cover number theory in much depth, staying at the level of basic parity arguments and the basic definition of modular congruence. We don’t cover topics like Bézout’s identity, the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, Euclid’s lemma, etc. We instead use very basic number theory as a proving ground for elementary proof techniques.
Lagrange’s four-square theorem is a beautiful and somewhat surprising result I’ve always wanted to teach in my course. The problem is that the proof relies on many techniques that are way above what we cover in the class (unique factorization into primes, the three-square theorem, etc.)
I’ve always wondered if there’s a much simpler proof that would show every number is the sum of $k$ squares for some constant $k \gt 4$. Ideally, such a proof would rely only on the most basic properties of number theory (e.g. the idea that every number leaves a remainder when divided by another, basic parity arguments, etc.). A good example of the style of argument that would meet students where they are would be the classic proof that all integers are the sum of five cubes, which essentially boils down to a case argument on the remainder of the integer mod 6.
Is there a very simple proof that all natural numbers are the sum of at most $k$ squares for some small constant $k$?

Hardy and Wright   do a short elementary  proof. Section 20.5, pages 302-303 in the fifth edition. Theorems 369 and 370

uses theorem 87 on page 70

Addition:  after Robert's comment, I suggest that proving that any positive integer is the product of primes is not that hard; more work is required for uniqueness. But uniqueness is not required here
Hardy and Wright, not sure what edition




In order to go from "every prime is the sum of four squares" to "every positive integer is the sum of four squares" you need the fact that every positive integer is a product of primes. This is part of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, which OP wrote they don't cover.
